# no output in Eclipse console of Character.MIN_VALUE

Tags: java, eclipse

I train myself in Java and have a problem I can not solve for the first time.
I searched for solutions, but didn't find anything.

So my Problem is that Eclipse (Version3.8.1) don't show the output in console of this lines:

```
System.out.println( "Char min.: " + Character.MIN.VALUE );
System.out.println( "Char max.: " + Character.MAX.VALUE );
```

The result in console is:

```
Char min.:
Char max.:
```

Should i change some properties to display the correct output ?

Here is my whole code, nothing special:

```
public class PrimDatentypen {

// primitive Datentypen - Ausgabe von Wertebereichen

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println( "Byte min.: " + Byte.MIN_VALUE );           // -128
    System.out.println( "Byte max.: " + Byte.MAX_VALUE );           // 127
    System.out.println( "Char min.: " + Character.MIN_VALUE );      // '\u0000'
    System.out.println( "Char max.: " + Character.MAX_VALUE );      // '\uFFFF'
    System.out.println( "Int min.: " + Integer.MIN_VALUE );         // -2147483648
    System.out.println( "Int max.: " + Integer.MAX_VALUE );         // 2147483647
    System.out.println( "Double min.: " + Double.MIN_VALUE );       // 4.9E-324
    System.out.println( "Double max.: " + Double.MAX_VALUE );       // 1.797...E308
}
```

}

Thanks a lot for your support :)

Comment: Well, some characters are invisible. If you want the numeric min value, use `System.out.println( "Char min.: " + (int) Character.MIN_VALUE);`

Comment: Ok, it shows me the numerical range of char. But it should be shown the result '\u0000' and '\uFFFF'. This is what the code example shows me (Java ist auch eine Insel - Christian Ullenbloom (http://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/javainsel/javainsel_02_003.html#dodtp070cd74f-8bb2-43fc-bbe4-fd5a9499b793) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum value of Char is the character with the value of 0.  This is not the same as the character which represents '0'.  '0' is ascii is represented by the bytes with a decimal value of 48(see http://www.asciitable.com/).
The bytes with a value of 0 represent the 'NUL' character which will not be output on the console as there's no representation of 'NUL'. In fact the first 6 characters in ascii are largely regarded as unprintable characters.

So the answer to your question is no, you shouldn't change anything, as you are already displaying the correct output.

If you edit you code to iterate all the values from Character.MIN_VALUE to Character.MAX_VALUE you'll see the whole ascii table printed and see how there's no representation of the first few characters.

e.g.

```
for (char i = Character.MIN_VALUE; i <= Character.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
   System.out.println(System.out.format("Decimal representation: %d: ASCII:***%c", ((int)i), ((char)i)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Try below code you will get correct output:

```
System.out.println("Char min.: " + (int)Character.MIN_VALUE);

System.out.println("Char max.: " + (int)Character.MAX_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a difference between `0` and `'0'`

`0` - 'null' and `'0'`- 48

Comment: This is already answered (1st answer) with detailed explanation.